# HTML textarea is showing HTML characters

Tags: php

I am using this PHP Code:

```
($result["address1"] ? $result["address1"].'&#10;' : '')
.($result["address2"] ? $result["address2"].'&#10;' : '')
.($result["address3"] ? $result["address3"].'&#10;' : '')
.($result["town"] ? $result["town"].'&#10;' : '')
.($result["county"] ? $result["county"].'&#10;' : '')
.($result["postcode"] ? $result["postcode"] : '')
```

after each line, i want to show a line break but not the HTML code.

using the above is displaying the `&#10;` i have also tried using `<br />`, `\n` and `\r` but they all show too

Comment: Try: PHP_EOL (without quotes around).

Comment: like PHP_EOL($result["address1"].'<br>'.$result["address2"]); ?>

Comment: Use it where you want to break the line. Like: `$result["address1"] . PHP_EOL`

Comment: @Hatef works great - create an answer so  ican accept :) thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned earlier in comments, you could use something like the code below to achieve what you want:

```
$result["address1"] . PHP_EOL
```

Answer (score 2):

\n will work when wrapped in double-quotes, i.e. "\n", but it will not work when wrapped in single quotes, i.e. '\n'.

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this.

```
$output = null;

foreach($result AS $key => $value) {
    if (!empty($result[$key])) {
        $output .= $value.PHP_EOL;
    }
}

echo $output;
```